# Trouble understanding the tangent plane of a surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, plane-geometry, tangent-line

$$z = z_0 +a(x-x_o)+b(y-y_0)$$

where $a$ and $b$ are the partial derivates with respect to $x$ and $y$. I dont understad why $a$ and $b$ are there since they are tangent to the plane not normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ a $ and $ b $ are numbers, not vectors. If you rewrite your equation as
$$
a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+(-1)(z-z_0) = 0,
$$
you can see that the vector $ (a, b, -1) $ is perpendicular (normal) to your plane (which presumably meets the surface at the point $ (x_0, y_0, z_0) $). On the other hand, the lines
$$ 
\{ (x_0, y_0, z_0) + s \cdot (1, 0, a) \mid s \in \mathbb R \} = 
\{ (x_0 + s, y_0, z_0 + as) \mid s \in \mathbb R \}
$$
and
$$
\{ (x_0, y_0, z_0) + t \cdot (0, 1, b) \mid t \in \mathbb R \} = 
\{ (x_0, y_0 + t, z_0 + bt) \mid t \in \mathbb R \}
$$
are tangent to the surface (and therefore contained in the tangent plane). That is the geometric meaning of partial derivatives.

Comment: now everthing makes sense thank you!